# Mysql grouping - prioritize not null - possible?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm sorry for the lack of a decent title but I have no idea how else to explain this.

```
id     fk_id     name     attr1     attr2     attr3     attr4
---------------------------------------------------
1      1         test     1         null      null      null
2      1         testa    null      2         null      null
3      1         testb    null      null      3         null
4      1         testc    null      null      null      4
```

Is there a way to group this so that it returns

```
id     fk_id     name     attr1     attr2     attr3     attr4
---------------------------------------------------
1      1         test     1         2         3         4
```

Please let me know if you need anymore information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simpliest answer is using `MAX()` and `MIN()` in all columns but this is will sometimes give invalid result.

```
SELECT MIN(ID), fk_ID, MIN(name), 
       MAX(attr1) attr1, MAX(attr2) attr2, MAX(attr3) attr3, MAX(attr4) attr4
FROM   tableName
GROUP  BY fk_ID
```

Here's a solution that is better than the statement above,

```
SELECT  a.fk_ID, a.ID, a.Name,
        b.attr1, b.attr2, b.attr3, b.attr4
FROM    tableName a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  fk_id, MIN(id) ID,
                    MAX(attr1) attr1, MAX(attr2) attr2, 
                    MAX(attr3) attr3, MAX(attr4) attr4
            FROM    tablename
            GROUP   BY fk_id
        ) b ON a.fk_id = b.fk_id AND a.ID = b.ID
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  Works 100% and this solution dropped 7 joins from my report and reduced query time from seconds to milliseconds.  Side note I would upvote but apparently I don't have enough rep to.  Sorry.